# Add/subtract questions game

Tags: java, optimization, beginner, game

I am new to Java, and I would like some tips from the 'pros'. I know of the Pascal naming system, and things like that, but how can I improve this code?

**Menu.java**

```
package com.x12.addsubtract;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Subtract {

    Game game = new Game();
    String[] question = new String[game.numberOfQuestions];
    int[] questionAnswer = new int[game.numberOfQuestions];
    String[] userQuestionAnswerString = new String[game.numberOfQuestions];
    int[] userQuestionAnswerInt = new int[game.numberOfQuestions];
    Random rGen = new Random();
    int firstNumber;
    int secondNumber;
    int score;
    String tempQuestion;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Sum generation function
    public String makeSum(int id) {

        // Generate numbers in sum
        firstNumber = rGen.nextInt(9);
        secondNumber = rGen.nextInt(9);

        // Create question
        tempQuestion = firstNumber + " - " + secondNumber + " = ";

        // Work out question answer
        questionAnswer[id - 1] = firstNumber - secondNumber;

        // Return question answer
        return tempQuestion;
    }

    // Creation method
    Subtract() {

        // Print game mode and status information
        System.out.println("\nAdding game started!");
        System.out.println("Generating questions...");
        System.out.println("1 question = 100 points");
        System.out.println("Your time is subtracted from your score");

        // Print number generation [debug] information
        System.out.print("[ ");
        for (int qid = 1; qid <= game.numberOfQuestions; qid++) {
            question[qid - 1] = makeSum(qid);
            System.out.print(qid + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("]");

        // Start timer
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // Ask the user the questions
        for (int qnum = 0; qnum < question.length; qnum++) {
            System.out.print(question[qnum]);
            userQuestionAnswerString[qnum] = input.nextLine();
        }

        long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // Convert to number
        for (int cQAS = 0; cQAS < userQuestionAnswerString.length; cQAS++) {
            try {
                userQuestionAnswerInt[cQAS] = Integer.parseInt(userQuestionAnswerString[cQAS]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error: Your answer for question " + (cQAS + 1) + " is not a number!");
            }
        }

        // Check if user was correct
        for (int uQAI = 0; uQAI < userQuestionAnswerInt.length; uQAI++) {
            if (userQuestionAnswerInt[uQAI] == questionAnswer[uQAI]) {
                score += 1;
            }
        }
        int scoreMass = (int) ((score * 100) - ((finish-start)/1000));
        System.out.println("\nYou got " + score + " questions correct out of " + game.numberOfQuestions + ".\nYour score was " + scoreMass + ".");
        double totaltime = (finish-start) / 1000D;
        System.out.println("It took you " + totaltime + " seconds to do " + game.numberOfQuestions + " additions.");
        float spq = (float)totaltime/game.numberOfQuestions;
        System.out.println("That is an average of " + spq + " calculation(s) per second!");
    }
}
```

**Add.java**

```
package com.x12.addsubtract;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Add {

    Game game = new Game();
    String[] question = new String[game.numberOfQuestions];
    int[] questionAnswer = new int[game.numberOfQuestions];
    String[] userQuestionAnswerString = new String[game.numberOfQuestions];
    int[] userQuestionAnswerInt = new int[game.numberOfQuestions];
    Random rGen = new Random();
    int firstNumber;
    int secondNumber;
    int score;
    String tempQuestion;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Sum generation function
    public String makeSum(int id) {

        // Generate numbers in sum
        firstNumber = rGen.nextInt(9);
        secondNumber = rGen.nextInt(9);

        // Create question
        tempQuestion = firstNumber + " + " + secondNumber + " = ";

        // Work out question answer
        questionAnswer[id - 1] = firstNumber + secondNumber;

        // Return question answer
        return tempQuestion;
    }

    // Creation method
    Add() {

        // Print game mode and status information
        System.out.println("\nAdding game started!");
        System.out.println("Generating questions...");
        System.out.println("1 question = 100 points");
        System.out.println("Your time is subtracted from your score");

        // Print number generation [debug] information
        System.out.print("[ ");
        for (int qid = 1; qid <= game.numberOfQuestions; qid++) {
            question[qid - 1] = makeSum(qid);
            System.out.print(qid + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("]");

        // Start timer
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // Ask the user the questions
        for (int qnum = 0; qnum < question.length; qnum++) {
            System.out.print(question[qnum]);
            userQuestionAnswerString[qnum] = input.nextLine();
        }

        long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // Convert to number
        for (int cQAS = 0; cQAS < userQuestionAnswerString.length; cQAS++) {
            try {
                userQuestionAnswerInt[cQAS] = Integer.parseInt(userQuestionAnswerString[cQAS]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error: Your answer for question " + (cQAS + 1) + " is not a number!");
            }
        }

        // Check if user was correct
        for (int uQAI = 0; uQAI < userQuestionAnswerInt.length; uQAI++) {
            if (userQuestionAnswerInt[uQAI] == questionAnswer[uQAI]) {
                score += 1;
            }
        }
        int scoreMass = (int) ((score * 100) - ((finish-start)/1000));
        System.out.println("\nYou got " + score + " questions correct out of " + game.numberOfQuestions + ".\nYour score was " + scoreMass + ".");
        double totaltime = (finish-start) / 1000D;
        System.out.println("It took you " + totaltime + " seconds to do " + game.numberOfQuestions + " additions.");
        float spq = (float)totaltime/game.numberOfQuestions;
        System.out.println("That is an average of " + spq + " calculation(s) per second!");
    }
}
```

**Subtract.java**

```
package com.x12.addsubtract;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Subtract {

    Game game = new Game();
    String[] question = new String[game.numberOfQuestions];
    int[] questionAnswer = new int[game.numberOfQuestions];
    String[] userQuestionAnswerString = new String[game.numberOfQuestions];
    int[] userQuestionAnswerInt = new int[game.numberOfQuestions];
    Random rGen = new Random();
    int firstNumber;
    int secondNumber;
    int score;
    String tempQuestion;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Sum generation function
    public String makeSum(int id) {

        // Generate numbers in sum
        firstNumber = rGen.nextInt(9);
        secondNumber = rGen.nextInt(9);

        // Create question
        tempQuestion = firstNumber + " - " + secondNumber + " = ";

        // Work out question answer
        questionAnswer[id - 1] = firstNumber - secondNumber;

        // Return question answer
        return tempQuestion;
    }

    // Creation method
    Subtract() {

        // Print game mode and status information
        System.out.println("\nAdding game started!");
        System.out.println("Generating questions...");
        System.out.println("1 question = 100 points");
        System.out.println("Your time is subtracted from your score");

        // Print number generation [debug] information
        System.out.print("[ ");
        for (int qid = 1; qid <= game.numberOfQuestions; qid++) {
            question[qid - 1] = makeSum(qid);
            System.out.print(qid + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("]");

        // Start timer
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // Ask the user the questions
        for (int qnum = 0; qnum < question.length; qnum++) {
            System.out.print(question[qnum]);
            userQuestionAnswerString[qnum] = input.nextLine();
        }

        long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // Convert to number
        for (int cQAS = 0; cQAS < userQuestionAnswerString.length; cQAS++) {
            try {
                userQuestionAnswerInt[cQAS] = Integer.parseInt(userQuestionAnswerString[cQAS]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error: Your answer for question " + (cQAS + 1) + " is not a number!");
            }
        }

        // Check if user was correct
        for (int uQAI = 0; uQAI < userQuestionAnswerInt.length; uQAI++) {
            if (userQuestionAnswerInt[uQAI] == questionAnswer[uQAI]) {
                score += 1;
            }
        }
        int scoreMass = (int) ((score * 100) - ((finish-start)/1000));
        System.out.println("\nYou got " + score + " questions correct out of " + game.numberOfQuestions + ".\nYour score was " + scoreMass + ".");
        double totaltime = (finish-start) / 1000D;
        System.out.println("It took you " + totaltime + " seconds to do " + game.numberOfQuestions + " additions.");
        float spq = (float)totaltime/game.numberOfQuestions;
        System.out.println("That is an average of " + spq + " calculation(s) per second!");
    }
}
```

**Game.java**

```
package com.x12.addsubtract;

public class Game {

    public int numberOfQuestions = 15;

    public void startGameAdd() {
        new Add();
    }

    public void startGameSubtract() {
        new Subtract();
    }
}
```

Comment: It appears you added subtract class twice instead of menu

Comment: An initial thought is that the display logic is mixed with core game logic i.e. System.out.println mixed in with the actual game.  First idea I would potentially look at is abstracting these two concepts out perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to java :), it is not hard to get into the OO mindset. But you might have to unlearn the procedural way of thinking.

A few thoughts to help you along ,

(The Menu.java is missing. So I couldn't look at it)

- You seem to be using Game.numberOfQuestions as a static final constant. Why not name it so? This would also make sure that you dont have to instantiate it to access the member.
- There does not seem to be any difference between Add.java and Subtract.java except for a single character. (Diff below)

  ```
  + Add.java: tempQuestion = firstNumber + " + " + secondNumber + " = ";
  - Subtract.java: tempQuestion = firstNumber + " - " + secondNumber + " = ";
  31c31
  + Add.java:questionAnswer[id - 1] = firstNumber + secondNumber;
  - Subtract.java:questionAnswer[id - 1] = firstNumber - secondNumber;
  ```

I think you should abstract both Add.java and Subtract.java into a parent class. (use the Game class itself) and make it define a protected method op() that takes two numbers, and does an operation on them. Override them in Add.java with addition and in Subtract.java with subtraction.

This should allow the duplication to go away.

```
class Subtract extends Game {
   public String name() { return "Subtract"; }
   public String opStr() { return "-"; }
   public int op(int a, int b) { return a - b; }
}

class Add extends Game {
   public String name() { return "Add"; }
   public int opStr() { return "+"; }
   public int op(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
}
```

- An advice, it is better to take out the println statements from the middle of your logic. They only serve to obscure it. If possible, isolate them to separate methods.

```
    package com.x12.addsubtract;
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public abstract class Game {

        static final int numberOfQuestions = 15;

        public abstract String name();
        public abstract String opStr();
        public abstract int op(int a, int b);


        String[] question = new String[numberOfQuestions];
        int[] questionAnswer = new int[numberOfQuestions];
```

Avoid excessively long variable names. I know that various books advocate longer variable names, but often they take away from your screen real-estate,

Also, try to restrict the width of your statements to about 100 characters. It is a little more easier on the eye of the reader.

```
        String[] userQAString = new String[numberOfQuestions];
        int[] userQAInt = new int[numberOfQuestions];
        Random rGen = new Random();
```

Declare the variables at the place you want to use them. Here, firstNumber, secondNumber etc are to be moved to makeSum method.

```
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Avoid excessive comments. Especially if the comment only describes the algorithm. Instead, focus on why a function does what it does. A general thumb rule is to focus on the outside rather than the inside. That is, the comment should describe how the function fits into the larger scheme of things.

Also avoid extra variables if possible. They only serve to clutter you code.

```
    public String makeSum(int id) {
        int firstNumber = rGen.nextInt(9);
        int secondNumber = rGen.nextInt(9);

        questionAnswer[id - 1] = op(firstNumber, secondNumber);
        return firstNumber + opName() + secondNumber + " = ";
    }

    void banner() {
        System.out.println(name () + "game started!");
        System.out.println("Generating questions...");
        System.out.println("1 question = 100 points");
        System.out.println("Your time is subtracted from your score");
        System.out.print("[ ");
        for (int qid = 1; qid <= numberOfQuestions; qid++) {
            question[qid - 1] = makeSum(qid);
            System.out.print(qid + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("]");
    }

    void getUserInput() {
        // Ask the user the questions
        for (int qnum = 0; qnum < question.length; qnum++) {
            System.out.print(question[qnum]);
            userQAString[qnum] = input.nextLine();
        }
```

I am unsure if it was intended to be this way (allow user to input all answers before validating) otherwise, combine the below loop with above.

```
        for (int cQAS = 0; cQAS < userQAString.length; cQAS++) {
            try {
                userQAInt[cQAS] = Integer.parseInt(userQAString[cQAS]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error: Your answer for question " 
                     + (cQAS + 1) + " is not a number!");
            }
        }
    }

    Game() {
        banner();
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        getUserInput();
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        int score = 0;
        // Check if user was correct
        for (int uQAI = 0; uQAI < userQAInt.length; uQAI++) {
            if (userQAInt[uQAI] == questionAnswer[uQAI]) score++;
        }
        result(score, time);
    }
```

Separate out these from your main logic.

```
    void result(int score, long time) {
        double totaltime = time / 1000D;
        int scoreMass = (int) ((score * 100) - totalTime));
        System.out.println("\nYou got " + score + " questions correct out of " 
             + numberOfQuestions + ".\nYour score was " + scoreMass + ".");
        System.out.println("It took you " + totaltime + " seconds to do " 
             + numberOfQuestions + " additions.");
        float spq = (float)totaltime/numberOfQuestions;
        System.out.println("That is an average of " + spq + " calculation(s) per second!");
    }
}
```

---

There is something seriously wrong with the markdown, I cann't get the code quotes to work right anymore. It was working until yesterday.

Comment: umm, where is that last code segment going?  It looks the same as the original code i.e. still has println' in it etc ??

Comment: @dreza you might have seen a partial answer :) check if it answers your question now.

Comment: yep does now :)

Comment: I think `op` and `opStr` are taking *"saving screen real estate"* too far. If `Game` were called `Operator` (as it should be if `Add` and `Subtract` inherit from it), one could use `calculate` and `getSymbol` as method names  instead.

Comment: Hmm I agree :). And the Game should be called Operator or Operation.

Comment: it's a good answer, by the way.